# replacing specific lines below the line containing a certain string using sed inplace editing in linux

Tags: linux, sed, edit

I am trying to script the automatic input of file, which is as follows

```
*CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE
$#     cid                                                                 title
$#    ssid      msid     sstyp     mstyp    sboxid    mboxid       spr       mpr
     1         2         3         3         0         0         0         0
$#      fs        fd        dc        vc       vdc    penchk        bt        dt
0.0100          0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000         0     0.000 1.0000E+7
$#     sfs       sfm       sst       mst      sfst      sfmt       fsf       vsf
1.000000  1.000000     0.000     0.000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
*CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE
$#     cid                                                                 title
$#    ssid      msid     sstyp     mstyp    sboxid    mboxid       spr       mpr
     1         3         3         3         0         0         0         0
$#      fs        fd        dc        vc       vdc    penchk        bt        dt
0.0100          0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000         0     0.000 1.0000E+7
$#     sfs       sfm       sst       mst      sfst      sfmt       fsf       vsf
1.000000  1.000000     0.000     0.000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
```

I want to changed fifth line after the string

```
 *CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE
```

with a line from other file  frictionValues.txt

What I am using is as follows

```
sed -i -e '/^\*CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE/{n;n;n;n;n;R frictionValues.txt' -e 'd}' input.txt
```

but this changes all the 5 lines after the string but it reads the values 2 times from the file frictionValues.txt. I want that it reads only first line and then copy it at all the instance where it finds the string. Can anybody tell me using sed with inplace editing like this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (I might be well off the mark as to what you want!):

```
sed '1s|.*|1{x;s/^/&/;x};/^\*CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE/{n;n;n;n;n;G;s/.*\\n//}|;q' frictionValues.txt |
sed -i -f - input.txt
```

Explanation:

- Build a `sed` script from the first line of the `frictionValues.txt` that stuffs the said first line into the hold space (HS). The remaining script is as before but instead of `R frictionValues.txt` appends the HS to the pattern space using `G`.
- Run the above `sed` script against the `input.txt` file using the `-f -` switch the `sed` script is passed via `stdin` from the previous pipeline.

Comment: you are quite near. it works well  like get the line from frictionvalues.txt and copy it to the 5 line below the string, the only problem is that it is copying at the 5 place and not deleting the 5 line. I mean it should replace it .   other functionality is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

Content of `frictionValues.txt`:

```
monday 
tuesday
```

Content of `input.txt` will be the same that you pasted in the question.

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## Match literal string.
/^\*CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE/ { 

    ## Append next five lines.
    N   
    N   
    N   
    N   
    N   

    ## Delete the last one.
    s/\(^.*\)\n.*$/\1/

    ## Print the rest of lines.
    p   

    ## Queue a line from external file.
    R frictionValues.txt

    ## Read next line (it will the external one).
    b   
}

## Print line.
p
```

Run it like:

```
sed -nf script.sed input.txt
```

With following result:

```
*CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE
$#     cid                                                                 title
$#    ssid      msid     sstyp     mstyp    sboxid    mboxid       spr       mpr
     1         2         3         3         0         0         0         0
$#      fs        fd        dc        vc       vdc    penchk        bt        dt
monday 
$#     sfs       sfm       sst       mst      sfst      sfmt       fsf       vsf
1.000000  1.000000     0.000     0.000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
*CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE
$#     cid                                                                 title
$#    ssid      msid     sstyp     mstyp    sboxid    mboxid       spr       mpr
     1         3         3         3         0         0         0         0
$#      fs        fd        dc        vc       vdc    penchk        bt        dt
tuesday
$#     sfs       sfm       sst       mst      sfst      sfmt       fsf       vsf
1.000000  1.000000     0.000     0.000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
```

Comment: Nice answer, glad to boost you over 3000! ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @Birei the script I am using has already arround 100 lines, so thats why I request for the sed like I used before which I can embedd my current script. another script will complicate the things, anyways thanks for your detailed answer. but if possible please  help me with that.

Comment: the explanation is great, I must admit

Answer (score 1):

I got a two step approach :
First find out the line number that has your matching text:

```
linenum=`grep -m 1 \*CONTACT_FORMING_ONE_WAY_SURFACE_TO_SURFACE input.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Now, combine `sed` commands to replace based on line number.
Change data at linenum+5 with value from "frictionValues.txt" - and also, delete data at linenum+5

```
sed -e "$((linenum+5)) c `cat frictionValues.txt`" -e "$((linenum+5)) d" input.txt
```

**Assumptions**

frictionValues.txt - has only one line

You are using one of the modern Linux OSs

Comment: the probelm is that I am using a loop to read the values from the file of frictionValues.txt..  so frictionValues.txt donot have a single line, it has hundreds of lines with 1 nuumber on each line.